# Validation Rule in VBA to determine the length of text

Tags: vba, ms-access, validationrule

I have a form for recording the phone numbers which have two kinds:

- **Internal** has 4 characters
- **External** has 4 or 7 or 8 characters

I want to make the ValidationRule change according to the Combobox that determines the type of phone numbers.

I tried to use ValidationRule in the form properties but it doesn't work with `IIf` formula or dependening on the value of another textbox or combobox.

So I made this piece of code, but it doesn't work:

```
If me.combo.value = "internal" then 
    Me.field.validationrule = "Len([field]) = 4"
ElseIf Me.combo.value = "external" Then 
    Me.field.validationrule = "Len([field]) = 4 or Len([field]) = 7 or Len([field]) = 8"
End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the validation rule. Try something like this instead:

```
([combo]="internal" And Len([field])=4) Or ([combo]="external" And (Len([field])=4 Or Len([field])=7 Len([field])=8))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for which I  ask

```
If me.combo.value = "enteral"  then Me.field.validationrule ="Is Null OR Like """"" Elseif me.combo.value = "extetnal" then.   Me.field.validationRule="Is Null OR Like """" OR Like """"  OR Like """""
End if.
```

The source 
[https://www.officena.net/ib/topic/87200-التحكم-بخاصية-قاعدة-التحقق-من-الصحة-validationrule-لمربع-نص-برمجياً-vba/](https://www.officena.net/ib/topic/87200-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%82%D9%82-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%A9-validationrule-%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B9-%D9%86%D8%B5-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%8B-vba/)